# Have drop tables been created for non-void levels?

Tags: warframe

I've been grinding Illad on Phobos for Miter parts for a while now, and I am only missing the Blueprint now. However, I have had everything else for a while, and despite doing 4-5 more runs beyond that, I still have yet to find the BP. I looked around for a drop table for Lt Lech Kril (he drops the parts, not Vor), but all I can find is that he can drop all of the parts, and nowhere else has them. I would like to find a drop table (that lists what items he can drop, and what their chance of dropping is) so that I can estimate approximately how much longer I have to put up with those d###ed eviscerators -_-. Is there a website that already has one, or is there a way ***I*** can create on without doing thousands of runs myself?

Comment: Also, are certain missions more likely to drop a specific mod than others? (I stupidly fused my 3rd Excalibur ability into a common mod, and now I can't find another :[ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of Update 10.2 or 10.3, the drop tables have been encrypted. So, you cannot determine specific percentages of drops. However, as the Warframe wiki has indicated, each boss has a unique item which can be only dropped by them. Moreover, each of three factions has a tendency to drop certain mods and crafting materials over others.

Hopefully, this issue will be alleviated when the codex gets released...

EDIT:

I think there was an earlier version of the drop table released by creative crackers around a few weeks ago, but, it probably has become outdated with the recent patches.